# GMail API User is not authenticated

Tags: php, gmail-api

I am using this [GMailPHP](https://github.com/adevait/GmailPHP) and I have got my config file right. But I am getting this error-

```
User is not authenticated.
```

The code is as below as my target is running from the command line. I am thinking CLIENT ID and SECRET are needed for getting OAuth Token. I need not get OAuth Token. I need to get Authenticated just using Config variables from Google Console for GMail.

```
<?php
    require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
    require_once('includes/config.php');

    use GmailWrapper\Authenticate;
    use GmailWrapper\Messages;
    $Authenticate= Authenticate::getInstance(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, APPLICATION_NAME, DEVELOPER_KEY);
    $Message= new Messages($Authenticate);

    $send = $Message->send('random_name@random_email_domain.com', 'GMail Testing', 'GMail API');
    if(!$send['status']){
        echo $send['message'];
        exit;
    }
    echo 'Message sent. See details below.<br/>';
    echo '<pre>';
    file_put_contents('data.txt', print_r($send['data'], true));
```

Comment: Can you sign in to the google account you are trying to use and verify on the security settings if you've allowed less secure apps to sign in?

Comment: Allow less secure apps: ON but same error.